# What's a good hash for an object with two strings and two BOOLs?

Tags: objective-c, hashcode, equality

What's a good hash for a class with two strings and two BOOLs?

e.g.

```
@interface Person : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *identifier;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL hasSpecialAbility;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL hasEmotion;

- (BOOL)isEqualToPerson:(Person *)person;

@end

- (NSUInteger)hash {
  // Is this good or should I skip the BOOLs?
  return identifier.hash ^ name.hash ^ hasSpecialAbility ^ hasEmotion;
}

- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object {
  ...
}

- (BOOL)isEqualToPerson:(Person *)person {
 ...
}
```

Comment: Not clever. Four BOOL combinations only give two different hashes. After changing all instance variables to start with an underscore, write ... ^ (_hasSpecialAbility << 0) ^ (_hasEmotion << 1).

Comment: `identifier.hash ^ name.hash ^ (hasSpecialAbility ? 1 : 0) ^ (hasEmoticon ? 2 : 0)`

Comment: @gnasher729 What about ... ^ (hasSpecialAbility | (hasEmotion << 1))?

Comment: In general you have no guarantee that a BOOL is any specific value -- `YES` is any non-zero value.

Answer (score 0):

If `r1`, `r2`, etc, are non-matching random numbers then I usually go with something like:

```
(bool1 ? r1 : r2) ^
(bool2 ? r3 : r4)
```

... on the grounds that adopting a more uniform approach is likely to lead to hash collisions between instances of different classes in any mixed-object container, and anything that saves an extra call to `isEqual:` is worth it.

Comment: Your argument only makes sense if the NSString hash values are not reasonably uniform.

Comment: @HotLicks I suggest you reread it. It explicitly talks about "instances of different classes". Maybe you've never written a class that didn't contain at least one `NSString` but I'll wager that's not true for almost everyone else.

Comment: I'm saying that so long as the hash algorithm used by NSString is reasonably uniform (and the consumer of the hash is reasonably coded) then it makes no difference.

Comment: @HotLicks then you're suffering a failure of comprehension. I create `ClassA` and `ClassB`. Each has two `BOOL` properties. Neither knows of the other. `ClassC` uses instances of both as e.g. keys to a single dictionary. What on earth does `NSString` have to do with reducing the probability of collisions? So if you had to advocate a general policy, what would it be? Read my answer again.